# Personal Catalog with Echo Nest API

Tags: objective-c, echonest

I am trying to create an app for the iPhone which creates a playlist based on the songs on the device. I want it to be able to analyze the songs currently on the device and then have the app create a playlist that contains only the song that the device has. I am using the echo nest API to get information about the song and to create the playlist using on the songs on the device. How can I create a personal catalog using the songs on the device then create a playlist using the personal catalog? Let me know if I'm not clear please.
Gilad

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you didn't found a solution or maybe for others looking
I just created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hsarret/9509322) with a small python script to answer your question

Here is a summary:

1. Create a Catalog with available songs
2. Create a playlist restricted to your catalog

Hope it helps